# Can AngularJS ngClass expressions be nested?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and have been assigned a maintenance task on an app we've inherited (originally developed for us by a third-party).

At the left of a header row in a table is a small button showing either a plus (+) or minus (-) symbol to indicate whether it will expand or collapse the section when clicked. It does this using ngClass as follows.

```
ng-class="{false:'icon-plus',true:'icon-minus'}[day.expanded]"
```

I have to remove the button when there is no data in the section and thus no ability to expand. There is already a class (.plus-placeholder) for this and I was wondering if the expressions that ngClass uses can be nested to allow something like this

```
ng-class="{false:'plus-placeholder',true:{false:'icon-plus',true:'icon-minus'}[day.expanded]}[day.hasTrips]"
```

which would allow me to add a `hasTrips` property to `day` to accomplish the task.

If this is not possible I think I will need to add a property something like `expandoState` that returns strings 'collapsed', 'expanded' and 'empty'. so I can code the ngClass like this

```
ng-class="{'collapsed':'icon-plus','expanded':'icon-minus','empty':'plus-placeholder'}[day.expandoState]"
```

And perhaps this is a cleaner way to do it in any case. Any thoughts/suggestions? Should it be relevant, the app is using AngularJS v1.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly **can** do either of the two options you have mentioned. The second is far preferable to the first in terms of readable code.

The `expandoState` property you mention should probably be a property or a method placed on the scope. Your attribute would then read something like

```
ng-class="{'collapsed':'icon-plus','expanded':'icon-minus','empty':'plus-placeholder'}[expandoState()]"
```

To put this method on the scope you would need to find the relevant controller. This will probably be wherever `day` is assigned to the scope. Just add

```
$scope.expandoState = function() {
    // Return current state name, based on $scope.day
};
```

---

Alternatively, you could write a method on the controller like

```
$scope.buttonClass = function() {
    // Return button class name, based on $scope.day
};
```

that just returns the class to use. This will let you write the logic from your first option in a much more readable fashion. Then you can use

```
ng-class="buttonClass()"
```

Comment: Thanks, I particularly like that last option.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle to play around with this. It works quite nicely. http://jsfiddle.net/strandloper/bNJC9/